# high amplitude pulse for short time followed by long pulse of low amplitude

Tags: circuit-analysis, pulse

I am looking to get output pulse as shown in image with green color. As of now, I am using a trigger pulse, as shown in blue color, as a trigger input to 555 Timer IC in monostable (one shot) mode.

Now, I desire to get the same output pulse but the input should be a pulse itself instead of a trigger as shown in other image.

The input pulse should be 1s in duration and so as the output, but for 25ms the output pulse should be of high voltage and for remaining time (i.e 1000ms-25ms=975ms) it should be of low voltage.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Many Thanks!

[image: LTSpice circuit schematic]
[image: Problem image]

Comment: Step back and explain what you are trying to accomplish at a higher level.  This smells like you're asking about details of a method that is probably inappropriate in the first place.

Comment: Okay. It is like I have a input pulse of 5V for 1s time duration and I want my output to be as shown in the image, which means that for first 25ms the output should be high voltage (5V) and for remaining time corresponding to input pulse, the output should be low voltage (say 1V).

Comment: I want to achieve this without using micro-controller and programming, simply by a circuit.

Comment: What are you going to do with this pulse?  Why does it need this particular shape?

Comment: Instead of doing as I asked, you merely repeated the question.  You've demonstrated that getting to the bottom of this will be too tedious.  Screw this, I'm outta here.

Comment: I will feed this voltage pulse to a smart material wire, in which amount of voltage/current supplied raises or lowers its temperature which in turn produces actuating force.

Do you have any idea how to generate such pulse with the help of a circuit? Please, help!

Comment: Don't take it wrong please, Olin.

Comment: The simplest idea is to have two output pulses with differing amplitude and duration when an input pulse is provided.

Comment: You say you are driving a material which will heat. That implies a fair amount of current. So. Exactly how much current is needed in the short pulse, and how much current is needed in the long?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yes you are right. That implies the amount of current. I have already tried it for a proof-of-concept with arduino. But, I intend to use it in handheld devices so can't take arduino every time along. I have the measurement data. 5V as maximum output pulse for 25ms and later 1V long duration pulse would give sufficient amount of current as per the internal resistance of the smart wire which changes with the change in its temperature due to electrical heating.

Comment: I'm afraid Olin is right. You seem incapable of answering a straightforward question. So, one last time: "Exactly how much current is needed in the short pulse, and how much current is needed in the long?" And if you don't know what you need, how do you expect anyone to solve your problem?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast. In short pulse 1.16A and in long pulse 0.36A.

Comment: At this moment my first priority is to generate the voltage pulse as desired for two different amplitudes and duration. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two 555 chips (or one 556). One would generate the 25ms pulse and the other would generate 1000ms pulse. Both would be triggered at the same time on the rising edge of the input pulse.

I'd use an opamp in an non-inverting adder configuration while selecting the resistors to scale the first output to 4V and the second one to 1V. Here's an example:
[How to design a non inverting op amp adder for my circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72482/how-to-design-a-non-inverting-op-amp-adder-for-my-circuit)

EDIT: Here is a block diagram of the circuit I was talking about
[image]

Comment: Hi Alexxx, thank you for your valuable reply.

I have one more doubt, should I use 555 (or 556) in astable or monostable mode?

Comment: In all honesty, I dont think that your answer will provide enough current, @Alexxx. This is for heating smart wire, and although there is no current spec (please add this to the question Tanmay), I would estimate amps, not the 10s of milliamps we might get out of an opamp.

Comment: Monostable as you want to generate a single pulse every time the input pulse changes. Plus it looks like you may need to add an invert as 555 is triggered low and add an RC differentiator circuit to generate a short pulse to trigger the 555 timer.

Comment: @stefandz. My answer doesn't even mention the current. If you need more current add a big MOSFET driver on the output.

Comment: I realise that - I'm just pointing out to the OP because I think this may be a practical limitation of the approach. Also, adding a MOSFET driver and keeping it linear will not be trivial. I think a PWM approach would be more practical overall - might draw something up quickly as an alternative

Comment: Hi @Alexxx, I tried to build up the circuit as you suggested. I generated an input pulse as desired. input pulse is then fed to inverter then i amplified it as inverter output is either 1 or 0. It is followed by RC differentiator circuit to have trigger pulses. Till here everything is working fine. But then, when i use them to trigger 555 in monostable mode. I am not getting 25ms pulse.

I created the schematic in LTSpice.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are clearly going to need a fair bit of current out of this circuit (to heat the wire) I would recommend using [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) as opposed to a linear waveform like this. It will be more efficient and will not require a linear power amplifier, which an op-amp based circuit would do.

My personal preference would **VERY STRONGLY** be to use a small 8-bit microcontroller, as this would ease customisation and tweaking and dramatically reduce component count. You would have an input pin for the input pulse, and then implement logic inside to have 25ms on pulse (100% PWM duty cycle) initially, followed by a 20% duty cycle PWM signal until the input drops low again. We're talking a couple of dozen lines of code to do this.

However, since you asked to do this without a microcontroller...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwCbhp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This has got to be one of the more ridiculous circuits I have ever thrown up, but it should work. R2 sets PWM on time, R1 sets off time - I would probably use a variable resistor for tuning here, somewhere between 10k and 50k. M3 inverts the input pulse for U2, and C4 + R7 + D2 differentiate and clamp it to provide a negative-going trigger. U2 provides a 25ms on pulse to the smart wire via M2 when the input pulse rises and U1 provides a 20% duty cycle (ish) PWM signal into the base of M1. M2 and M1 are in an effective OR configuration, so when the 25 ms is on it overrides the 20% PWM, and when it stops the PWM takes over.

One nice feature of this circuit is that if your trigger pulse is shorter or longer than 1s, you don't need to adjust anything - U1 is just gated by the trigger and so will match its length.

Comment: really thanks for your schematic. I really appreciate your effort, but do I need to have a trigger to start the circuit. I am little confused. Because, in my question i mentioned, that i have to use a pulse instead of trigger.

One more thing, are the voltage pulses as desired can be generated through delay logic gates and then using voltage shifter to get the desired output voltage?

Thanks again!

Comment: To be fair, I find your schematic very hard to read. My circuit takes the input pulse that you show (a 1 second pulse, presumably 5V in amplitude) and outputs a 25ms 100% 5V pulse followed by a 5V 20% PWM burst the same length as the remainder of the input pulse. This isn't the 1V analogue voltage that you asked for, but a 20% 5V PWM signal provides the same power to the Smart Wire that 1V DC would, which gives you the same end result. I don't really understand your final statement either. Please - just use a small microcontroller! There are 8-pin devices out there for <$1 that will do this!

Comment: Hi @stefandz, I build up your circuit again in LTSpice because simulation in CircuitLab was taking too long time. It happens the same with LTSpice. Can I reduce the circuit just to give 25ms pulse with every input pulse?

Please help! and thanks again for all the efforts.

Comment: I have to provide my input pulse at the trigger point you have marked, right?

Comment: If you just want a 25ms pulse, remove U1 and its associated components. I simulated the circuit and it works fine. Here's a crazy idea - instead of getting obsessed with simulation, why not build it and see from there?! M1, M2 and M3 all need to be logic level fets, M1 & M2 need to be capable of 1A Id and should be <250m Ohms on-resistance at 5V Vgs. The indicated FDN337N should work fine. If you are going to simulate, it shouldn't take more than 20 minutes in any case - only simulate the first 60ms or so at a fine time-step (10us) and then repeat for just over 1 second at a 1ms.

Comment: CircuitLab always gives error - you must select at least one output to plot, albeit, I have chosen 6 - V(trig), V(g1), V(out), etc.

What more I have to do?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question. Search Electronics Stack Exchange to see if someone has answered it before - if not, start a new question and reference this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28987/discussion-between-tanmay-bhargava-and-stefandz).